# Codeigniter "The requested URL was not found" error

Tags: codeigniter

I've started building a new website using codeigniter. I've been trying to link pages internally but i'm not able to do it for some reason. This is one of the link from my code

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/index">Home</a>
```

When i click on this link, it says

```
The requested URL /basicsite/site/index was not found on this server.
```

'url' helper is loaded in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'html');
```

I've set the base_url as follows

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/basicsite';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Any my default controller is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

And the 'site' controller looks like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller
{

function Site()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/site_header');     
    $this->load->view('content');       
    $this->load->view('templates/site_footer');
}

}
```

Don't know where i'm going wrong. Do i need to do something with the .htaccess file? I've gone through the similar questions on stackoverflow website but could not find a solution
Need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `http://localhost/basicsite/index.php/site/index` work for you?

Comment: @cryptic  yes, but for some reason images are not loading as it does for `http://localhost/basicsite/`

Comment: How are you loading the images? Please post an example generated image URL as output in the HTML source. Also please post where your images are located.

Comment: You need to have a slash at the end of your site url in the config.php. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/basicsite/';`

Comment: This is the URL generated `<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="128" height="148" alt="Logo" />`. Images are located in 'C:\wamp\www\basicsite\images'

Comment: `<img src="/images/logo.jpg" width="128" height="148" alt="Logo" />` Should work for linking images. If you don't have the first slash, then the link is relative to the current directory.

Comment: @Jeemusu  slash at the end of site url did not work. Also `<img src="/images/logo.jpg"....` did not work

Comment: Still, you need the slash at the end of the `base_url` in your config. If you read the config files comments it states -  `URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash:`

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, i added a slash

Comment: Sorry, you may need to include `basicsite` in your images url, so `="/basicsite/images/logo.jpg"` or alternatively `<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/logo.jpg" width="128" height="148" alt="Logo" />`

Comment: @Jeemusu  thanks. that solved one of my problems. Images are loading fine now. But the hyperlinks are not working yet.

Comment: Hmm, odd if they are as you posted they should work `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/index">Home</a>` . If you go directly to `http://localhost/basicsite/index.php/site/index` it loads right? What url are your links taking you to?

Comment: @Jeemusu  it seems like I finally got that. I had to add `index.php` in the anchor tag. So the tag changes from `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/index">Home</a>` to `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/site/index">Home</a>`. Should I add index.php every time? Is there a way to just avoid that?

Comment: Apparently, the base_url() is not reading the config['base_url']. Maybe it is With that kind of bug, always do a blank page to test what really is written by the php code. So `<?php echo "base func: ". base_url(); echo "<br>config base url: ". $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>` on a blank controller area could help you see what is really being written. Also, docs say to add the destination to the function. "... you can supply segments as a string or an array. Here is a string example:
`echo base_url("blog/post/123");`

Answer (score 0):

Remove index.php from your config file.